# Xamarin AutoSuggestBox Text not set from codebehind

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I've tried setting the code directly in code, and binding it to a property (and triggering the PropertyChangedEventHandler). But the front-end is not updating.

The approach I've taken seems to work for some of the native controls (I adapted my code for the next control on the form (a Picker which binds it's ItemsSource to a property calculated from the same value that I'm trying to bind the AutoSuggestBox Text to.

my xaml looks like this.

```
 <forms:AutoSuggestBox x:Name="locationAutoSuggestBox" 
 PlaceholderText="Enter site"
 TextChanged="LocationAutoSuggestBox_TextChanged"
 QuerySubmitted="LocationAutoSuggestBox_QuerySubmitted"
 SuggestionChosen="LocationAutoSuggestBox_SuggestionChosen"
 Text="{x:Binding SelectedSiteStr, Mode=TwoWay}" />

<Picker x:Name="pickerShift" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
Title="Select shift" ItemsSource="{x:Binding ShiftsForLocation}">
</Picker>
```

The relevant section of my viewmodel code looks like this.

```
    private Sites selectedSite;
    public Sites SelectedSite
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedSite;
        }
        set
        {
            selectedSite = value;
            if(selectedSite != null)
            {
                selectedSiteStr = selectedSite.SiteName;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedSiteStr"); 
                OnPropertyChanged("ShiftsForLocation");
            }
        }
    }

    private string selectedSiteStr = string.Empty;
    public string SelectedSiteStr
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedSiteStr;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                selectedSiteStr = value;
                if (AllSites != null)
                {
                    var site = AllSites.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SiteName.ToLower() == value.ToLower());
                    if (site != null)
                    {
                        selectedSite = site;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }        

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

The binding to ShiftsForLocation is working (it is calculated using the selectedSite, but the binding for SelectedSiteStr is not, and I can trace the code pulling the correct value from the property.

I am stumped. Any help appreciated.

Josh

Comment: `x:Binding`? Shouldn't it be direct like `Binding`

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else runs into it, I fixed it by upgrading from 0.1.0 to 0.6.0. I had to include the pre-release version of this library which I'm not keen on an embedded device which will be out of mobile/wifi coverage most of the time, but it seems to work.

Josh